# Join table not being populated in @Transactional test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testing, hsqldb

I have following test:

```
@Test
public void createNewShopAndCheckUserShopsCollection()
{
    //given
    ShopEntity shop = new ShopEntity();
    String shopName = "test shop";

    MallEntity mall = new MallEntity();
    mall.setId(1L);

    UserEntity user = userService.findOne(1L);
    int shopsModeratedBefore = user.getModeratedShops().size();

    shop.setMall(mall);
    shop.setName(shopName);
    shop.setModerators(Collections.singletonList(user));


    ShopEntity savedShop = shopRepository.save(shop);
    user = userService.findOne(1L);

    assertThat(user.getModeratedShops()).hasSize(shopsModeratedBefore + 1);
}
```

in class annotated with @Transactional. I need to roll back after its execution, so other tests won't fail. However, it seems, that join table is not being populated before end of method (assertion is falling). How can I manually make sure it gets updated?

Here is mapping in UserEntity.java

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "moderators")
@JsonBackReference(value = "moderatedShops")
@Setter
@Getter
private List<ShopEntity> moderatedShops;
```

And here in ShopEntity.java

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "shop_moderators",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@JsonManagedReference(value = "moderatedShops")
@Setter
@Getter
private List<UserEntity> moderators;
```

Comment: please, show also your entities classes, another thing is that I do not know if that kind of test is necessary. You are basically testing if you can insert something in db - you do not test any logic. Not sure if you are also using spring-boot but if you still want to test storing data in db maybe take a look at https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4#testing-the-jpa-slice

Comment: @pezetem i added entities. I know it does not not make much sense in real application, but i was just learning about using many to many relationship, added some methods in jpa repository related to that and I wanted to make sure that is working.